# WPF ShowDialog in started process is not blocking main window of current process

Tags: c#, wpf, process, showdialog

I have window application that starts process with WPF window. I send current process ID to the starting process, so WPF window can set owner properly:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
int parentProcessId = int.Parse(e.Args[0]);
System.Diagnostics.Process parentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(parentProcessId);
WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(mainWindow);
helper.Owner = parentProcess.MainWindowHandle;
mainWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Alt+Tab works as expected - WPF window blocks parent window. But it does not block parent widow's controls so I can push every button in parent window and even close it.

I'm starting new process like this:

```
string arguments = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "WPF.App.exe"), arguments);
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

How can I open WPF window so it blocks owner window's controls (and not only appears on top and blocks Alt+Tab)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the parent process is also a WPF app:

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    string arguments = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "WPF.App.exe"), arguments);
    childProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
    childProcess.Exited += childProcess_Exited;
    childProcessWaitFrame = new DispatcherFrame;
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(childProcessWaitFrame);
}

private void childProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    childProcessWaitFrame.Continue = false;
}
```